# Adding class to parent element where sub-child element input value is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When clicking on button `#btn-modal-clear` I would like to select and add a class to the `li` where it's `sub-child` input is empty `(value="")`. How do I do this?

**html:**

```
<li>...<li> 
<li>
    <a class="myCheckboxLink" tabindex="0">
        <span class="myCheckboxSpan">
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-check-checkbox" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <label class="radio">
            <input value="" type="radio">Name
        </label>
    </a>
</li>
<li>...<li>
```

**js:**

```
$('#btn-modal-clear').on('click', function() {  
    $('.select-name').multiselect('select', ['']);
    $('.select-name').multiselect('updateButtonText');

    ... .addClass("active"); 

});
```

So result should be:

**html:**

```
<li>...<li> 
<li class="active">
    <a class="myCheckboxLink" tabindex="0">
        <span class="myCheckboxSpan">
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-check-checkbox" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        <label class="radio">
            <input value="" type="radio">Name
        </label>
    </a>
</li>
<li>...<li>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ewm9pbqv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` with `.addClass()` in this case:

```
$('li').filter(function() { 
   return $(this).find('input:radio').val() == ""; 
}).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work. Please check it out:  https://jsfiddle.net/ewm9pbqv/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('li input[value=""]').closest("li").addClass('active');
```